# API Level não está de acordo

Tags: android, xml, sdk

Estou dando os meus primeiros passos no desenvolvimento para Android (hoje é o meu segundo dia de estudo). Vejam abaixo os meus arquivos de configuração e o erro que estou encontrando:

Inicialmente o meu **AndroidManifest.xml** estava assim:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Quando tentei inserir as seguintes linhas em meu **style.xml**:

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
```

Recebi o erro a seguir:

> @android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid requires API level 14
>   (current min is 11)

Então alterei o **AndroidManifest.xml** para:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Mas o erro persiste. Preciso fazer mais alguma alteração para ele reconhecer que eu alterei o **minSdkVersion** para 14?

PS.: Estou tentando seguir o *exemplo* encontrado neste link [aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground)

Comment: Se você estiver usando o **Eclipse** tente Project->Clean...

Comment: Adiciona como resposta. Funcionou!

Comment: Isto é uma situação recorrente no *Eclipse*. Quando algo que devia funcionar não funciona, tente primeiro usá-la antes de quebrar a cabeça à procura de uma solução.

Answer (score 1):

Basta dar Build > Rebuild Project , no caso do Intelli J ou Android Studio ou Project > Build Project, no caso do Eclipse.

Pesquise como utilizar a biblioteca appcompat-v7 ok.

Com ela você pode disponibilizar recursos gráficos de versões superiores do Andorid, como 4.0, 4.1.2, etc para rodar em versões mais antigas (a partir da API 7 ou 8 , se nãop me engano)